# replace multiple spaces by non breaking spaces

Tags: php, html, regex, pcre

How to replace all but first (white)spaces by `&nbsp;` when more than one space?

Specifically requested for use with php's `preg_replace`, so PCRE.

```
"This is     my text."
```

Should be converted into

```
"This is &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;my text."
```

Comment: Try `preg_replace("!\s+!", "&nbsp;", $text);`. Could you please provide an example?

Comment: Perhaps, you want `preg_replace("!\s{2,}!", "&nbsp;", $text);`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Example provided in question above.

Comment: This turns out an interesting problem. I cannot achieve it with `\G`. But I think you may just use `preg_replace('~(?<=\s)\s~', '&nbsp;', $s)` - see [this demo](https://ideone.com/IwSEzL).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems all you need is to replace each whitespace that is preceded with another whitespace symbol. Use a lookbehind-based approach:

```
(?<=\s)\s
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cbGsf3/1).

The `(?<=\s)` is a *positive lookbehind* that requires the presence of a whitespace immediately before  the current location, but the whitespace is not consumed, and is thus not replaced.

Below is a [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/IwSEzL):

```
$s = "This is     my text.";
echo preg_replace('~(?<=\s)\s~', '&nbsp;', $s);
// => This is &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;my text.
```

Answer (score 1):

More than one space is `>=2`

[PHP code demo](https://eval.in/763413)

```
<?php

echo preg_replace("!\s{2,}!", " &nbsp;", "Welcome to stack  overflow");
```

**Output:**

```
Welcome to stack &nbsp;overflow
```

Comment: It is possible that OP does not want the space before `&nbsp;`, and the replacement should be `"&nbsp;"` (without the initial space).

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is use [`Regex Lookahead & Lookbehind`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) like so:

Like so:

```
<?php
echo preg_replace("/\s(?=\s+)|(?<=\s)\s/", "&nbsp;", "Welcome to stack       overflow");
```

Outputs

```
Welcome to stack&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;overflow
```

Test it here: https://regex101.com/r/DGraSS/1 - provides good explications :)

Comment: This is nearly what I need, but I get an additional `&nbsp;` (eg 5 when there are just 4 spaces, 9 when having 8)
And it would be nicer to keep first space as is ("Welcome to stack &nbsp;&nbsp;) to allow breaks before

Comment: I just tested again under php 7.x and the number of spaces equals the number of outputted `nbsp`s.